# UberCard on D7. Not displaying the Username or Password correctly on new account

Tags: ubercart

hi all I'm using the ubercard module to setup a shop, all is working well, but at the end of a transaction there is a page which tells the user they have a new username and password which they can use to logon. This isn't being displayed all that is coming though is the special tokens !new_user_name and !new_password. I can't work out why its doing this, does anyone have a similar experience or is using this succesfully?

cheers